# ArgumentNullException when using Linq Select

Tags: c#, linq

I have a custom `Product` class. I am trying to populate a list of instances of that class. To do so, I am calling `ProductProxy.ProductById(id).Result` to receive a `JObject` with the information needed to construct the `Product` instance. I am able to construct the object without issue, but when trying to populate the list I receive an error:

> Exceptions: ArgumentNullException
>
> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<dynamic>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Product>'

```
List<string> items = new List<string>{"12345"};
List<Product> masterItemList = new List<Product>(0);
masterItemList = items.Select(id => ProductProxy.ProductById(id).Result.ToObject<Product>()).ToList();
```

How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: ArgumentNullException for an invalid cast is weird. What's the return type of `ToObject<T>`?

Comment: It looks like `ToObject<Product>()` return `dynamic` instead of `Product`

Comment: I'm assuming `ProductById` returns a `Task<T>`, in which case you should always use `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead of `.Result`

Comment: @BradM That wouldn't stop provoking this exception anyway

Comment: Try a `Cast<Product>()` before the `ToList`

Comment: insted of taking the output in  list try var or dynamic and after that you can mould the result

Comment: @BradM you should always use `await` if method signature allows you to

Comment: @juharr that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @juharr's comment, I was able to add a cast before the `ToList`

```
masterItemList = items.Select(id => ProductProxy.ProductById(id).Result.ToObject<Product>()).Cast<Product>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `ProductProxy.ProductById(id).Result` return a `null` value. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentnullexception?view=netframework-4.7.2).

> An ArgumentNullException exception is thrown when a method is invoked and at least one of the passed arguments is null but should never be null.